# Parsing JSON data with PHP

Tags: php, json, drupal

This is a bit of a noob question.  I'm working with a JSON file which looks something like this:

```
{"nodes": 
  [{"node": 
     {"Vocabulary name":"Bestseller Format",
      "Term":"Hardcover Fiction",
      "Bestseller1":"9780470227800",
      "Bestseller2":"9781451617962",
      "Bestseller3":"9781439167397",
      "Bestseller4":"9781617750106",
      "Bestseller5":"9780385533300",
      "Bestseller6":"9780670022526",
      "Bestseller7":"9781609530358",
      "Bestseller8":"9780132358040",
      "Bestseller9":"9780596159771",
      "Bestseller10":"9780151014163",
      "Bestseller11":"9780393334807",
      "Bestseller12":"9780805090161"}
  }]
}
```

And I am trying to parse it in php.  I have come up with a script

```
<?php       
  $jsonurl = "http://www.xtracrunchy.com/pandpnewlook/?q=pandp/bestsellers";
  $json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,NULL, NULL, 0, 1000);
  $json_output = json_decode($json,true);

  $bestseller_array = $json_output[nodes][0][node];

  foreach ($bestseller_array as $key => $value)
  {
     print $key;
     print " - ";
     print $value;
     print "<br />";
   }

?>
```

I would like to be able to eventually build an ordered list of Bestseller ISBN's but the only output I get when I run this script is

Vocabulary name - Bestseller Format
Term - Hardcover Fiction

and when I add print count($bestseller_array); I only get 2 elements in the array.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: could you put code with `code` tags? and make everything readable... thanks :D

Comment: Fixed the formatting myself. Next time, add 4 spaces before each line of code.

Comment: what will show var_dump($bestseller_array); ?

Comment: try `print_r($json_output)` \n http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: when I do the print_r I get:  Array ( [nodes] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [node] => Array ( [Vocabulary name] => Bestseller Format [Term] => Hardcover Fiction ) ) ) ) Vocabulary name - Bestseller Format

Comment: No wait, just tested. That's all the information the JSON feed contains. It provides no ISBN list as in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, I strongly advise you make use of CURL instead of `file_get_contents()`, because in [some occasions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen), it won't work. But since it's not a part of the question, I won't talk about this any further.

Secondly, you're making use of unnamed literal constants, which is very bad.

```
$json_output[nodes][0][node];
```

Should be:

```
$json_output['nodes'][0]['node'];
```

See the [documentation here on why](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar).

Finally, the JSON string you wrote above doesn't match with what is returned on that url, and the script does work as expected on this "new" json.

Comment: Thanks.  This was actually really helpful.  It still isn't working but this sort of of points me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

@flakes if you visit the URL you have in your $jsonurl you only get:

```
{"nodes":[{"node":{"Vocabulary name":"Bestseller Format","Term":"Hardcover Fiction"}}]}
```

Are you sure you're not missing something from the URL?

Answer (score 0):

The output from the server doesn't match what you expect.

```
var_dump( $json );
//string(87) "{"nodes":[{"node":{"Vocabulary name":"Bestseller Format","Term":"Hardcover Fiction"}}]}"
```

Hope that helps...